# Load and keep variables / objects accessible between files in python Flask server

Tags: python, flask

When I start my flask app, I want it to immediately load an object, and I want this object to be available to functions defined in other files.

The way things are set up now is as follows:

```
object = someObjectToLoadAtServerStartAndAlwaysKeepInMemoryAndAccessFromAnyPyFile
```

In run.py, located in folder Project:

```
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

In __init__.py, located in Project/app:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

In views.py, located in Project/app:

```
from app import app
@app.route('/page')
def func():
  #access preloaded variable here#
```

Note that I want the object (which is saved to a file) to be loaded immediately after the app is started, and maintained forever as long as the app is running.  I have tried any number of things, defining the object everywhere I can, and using global, but it is never accessible to func()

If I define it on top of views.py, will it load even no one has used one of the @app.routes?

Comment: First, why you put `from app import app` in `views.py`? then, `__init.py__`? Do you mean `__init__.py`

Comment: If I don't have that in views.py, when I try to run stuff I get name 'app' is not defined.  app is defined inside \_\_init.py\_\_

Comment: Sorry for that, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

All right, after I change `__init.py__` to `__init__.py`, this will work:

**File tree**:

```
Project
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── views.py
└── run.py
```

**run.py**:

```
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

**app/__init__.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

**app/views.py**:

```
from app import app
@app.route('/page')
def func():
    return 'Hello'
```

Here is a demo:

[image: demo1]

[image: demo2]

Comment: Oops, mine was named \_\_init\_\_.py correctly.  The server runs.  I'm just not sure how to make my object available to ALL .py files.  For example, I can define the object in views.py or one of the other .py files but it seems that only the file in which it is defined can see it even if I use 'global'.  I'm just not sure how to load an object on server start, and keep it in memory always, and accessible from any .py file.  I clarified my question a bit.

Comment: Well, so you're question is that you want *global a module in the package* right?

Comment: Maybe.  I'm a bit new to this so I'm not sure if it's a module.  Basically, I have a large object saved to a file.  It takes a long time to load it and needs to be accessed from any other files (and their functions) and that contain @app.routes including but not limited to views.py.  I want this object to be loaded from the file immediately when the server starts, and maintained in memory because loading takes a long time.

Comment: Because I didn't write large project or a package(or module), so I didn't do something like this. But maybe there is a easy way to do this. Let me search about it.

Comment: And about your question: You want load a file and that's very large, so you don't want to write something like `from large_file import foobar` in all file(because that will import that file again again again...it will spends lots of time). So you just want to load it to memory once and then just call it. Is it?

Comment: Correct.  I'm not sure what python does when you do from x load y in every file.  Maybe it keeps it in memory.  It's hard for me to tell.

Comment: No problem, however I understand it :).

Comment: @CHP Well, I didn't find something that's useful. Maybe you could ask a new question. Oh, please remember accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at how the LoginManager manager instance 'lm' is handled in part 6 of the Flask Mega-Tutorial, that gives you a great example to work from.

Any object declared in the **init**.py for the app module is then accessed by a direct import in the relevant file (eg. 'from app import lm')

See if this makes things clearer: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins